# Alternatives to rpm -qa and rpm -ql in ubuntu

Tags: dpkg

I am following Linux CBT tutorials for RHEL to learn some LINUX basics.

If I want to know if a particular package is installed in ubuntu, I usually type dpkg -l and grep the needed name. Such as

`dpkg -l | grep cron`

Is it same as using

`rpm -qa | grep cron`

for Redhat based OSes?

That guy also uses `rpm -ql` to list the file locations. Such as

`rpm -ql crontabs`

Can some one tell me what exactly does rpm -ql list and how can I get a similar command in Ubuntu to list all relevant files like `rpm -ql crontabs`. (Right now, I use locate cron and it lists me every file)

Answer (score 10):

`dpkg -l <packagename>` gives you the status of the package

`dpkg -L <packagename>` gives you a list of files including their locations

see also the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)

Comment: And, `dpkg -S crontabs` tells you which package provides the `crontabs` file.